# Materializecss collapsibles not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I've recently started making websites using materializecss. Everything has gone well, except I couldn't get collapsibles working correctly. They appear to my website, but they aren't clickable at all. I have imported all the css & js files, but that didn't seem to help it.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul class="collapsible">
            <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
            </li>
        </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

I got all the stylesheets and scripts, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was you have not initialized `collapsible` that's why it was not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked <3 Sadly I couldn't give you an upvote, but consider this thank you as one.

Comment: I believe that the real problem was that  you need to load jquery.js **before** materialize.js

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [Initialization step](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
   var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, {accordion: false});
});
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, {accordion: false});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```